# Can't get a page through $routeParams, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: angularjs

My problem is this: in the main page I have an ng-repeat of items as links, but they don't redirect correctly. Please be gentle, I'm learning AngularJS and what I found in the official documentation didn't help me, I hope you will.

page.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="PageCtrl as ctrl">
      <div ng-repeat="featured in ctrl.featured" class="text-centered">
        <h1>{{featured.titolo}}
          <small>{{featured.sottotitolo}}</small>
        </h1>
        <a ng-href="{{featured.id}}" class="thumbnail">
          <img class="img-responsive" alt="{{featured.etichetta}}" src="http://placehold.it/1518x1000" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

page.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('PageCtrl', function () {
    this.featured = [
      {
        id: '#/products/item',
        titolo: 'some text',
        sottotitolo: 'some text',
        etichetta: "some text"
      },
      {
        id: '#/products/item',
        titolo: 'some text',
        sottotitolo: 'some text',
        etichetta: "some text"
      },
      {
        id: '#/products/item',
        titolo: 'some text',
        sottotitolo: 'some text',
        etichetta: "some text"
      }
    ];
  });
```

app.js

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when(':productId', {
      templateUrl: 'views/products/:productId.html',
      controller: 'ItemCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'productId'
    })
});
```

/controllers/item.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ItemCtrl', function ($routeParams) {
    var self = this;
    self.productId = $routeParams.productId;
  });
```

Comment: Suggest you go through the routing part of tutorial on angular docs site. It's clear from your routing configuration you need a better understanding of how it works  https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Can't put wild cards/routeParams in `template` declaration without it being a function and your url declaration doesn't include all the path segments contained in the data

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it, I'll study that for sure dude. But can you say me what I'm doing wrong being more specific?